# Searching for a objectGUID in AD

Tags: .net, active-directory, directoryservices

I'm using the [Active Directory Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963907.aspx) from Mark Russinovich.
It is a great tool.

I'm using it to navigate active directory to make sure my program that uses DirectorySearcher from .NET returns correct data.

Something happens though, when I try to search inside my program with DirectorySearcher for objectGUID, if I pass in the actual GUID as a string it doesn't return anything, where as if I use [Active Directory Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963907.aspx), when I add

objectGuid with value f8d764ff-9a6a-418e-a641-b6f99661a8d5, its search clause becomes:
(objectGUID=\FFd\D7\F8j\9A\8EA\A6A\B6\F9\96a\A8\D5*)

How do I do this for directorySearcher in my program, I'm guessign it's an octet string thing, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [forums](http://directoryprogramming.net/forums/9/ShowForum.aspx) accompanying the excellent [The .NET Developer's Guide to Directory Services Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321350170) (Joe Kaplan / Ryan Dunn) is an excellent source for information like this.

Check out this thread here entitled [Find the object using objectGuid property](http://directoryprogramming.net/forums/thread/5551.aspx), which shows how you can convert a "regular" GUID to the S.DS "OctetString" format.

```
internal string ConvertGuidToOctetString(string objectGuid)
{
   System.Guid guid = new Guid(objectGuid);
   byte[] byteGuid = guid.ToByteArray();

   string queryGuid = "";

   foreach (byte b in byteGuid)
   {
       queryGuid += @"\" + b.ToString("x2");
   }

   return queryGuid; 
}
```

This could be slightly optimized by using a StringBuilder instead of consecutively concatenating together a string - but it seems fairly straightforward otherwise.

Hope this helps.

Marc

Comment: Wow, this took a minute to find! I'll add this was needed for myself using the Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard library to properly get the search function to parse my Guid... `ldapConnection.Search("baseDn", LdapConnection.SCOPE_ONE, "objectGUID =" + ConvertGuidToOctetString(objectGUID), attrs, false);`

Answer (score 5):

```
...
searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("objectGUID");

SearchResultCollection found = found = searcher.FindAll();

foreach (SearchResult result in found)
{
   Guid oGuid = new Guid((byte[])result.Properties["objectGUID"][0]);
}
...
```

Answer (score 3):

To get an Octet String usable by ADExplorer, apply these steps to the GUID string:

- first uppercase the GUID:

`F8D764FF-9A6A-418E-A641-B6F99661A8D5`

- split it on each dash into five parts:

`F8D764FF, 9A6A, 418E, A641, B6F99661A8D5`

- split each part into bytes (two hex digits each):

`{F8, D7, 64, FF}, {9A, 6A}, {41, 8E}, {A6, 41}, {B6, F9, 96, 61, A8, D5}`

- reverse the bytes of the first **three** parts:

`{FF, 64, D7, F8}, {6A, 9A}, {8E, 41}, {A6, 41}, {B6, F9, 96, 61, A8, D5}`

- disregard the division into parts:

`FF, 64, D7, F8, 6A, 9A, 8E, 41, A6, 41, B6, F9, 96, 61, A8, D5`

- prepend a backslash to every byte:

`\FF, \64, \D7, \F8, \6A, \9A, \8E, \41, \A6, \41, \B6, \F9, \96, \61, \A8, \D5`

- concatenate the bytes:

`\FF\64\D7\F8\6A\9A\8E\41\A6\41\B6\F9\96\61\A8\D5`